# CSS calc() - big equation

Tags: css

How to implement big equation using CSS calc() function?

I want to implement something like this:

```
width: calc(10px + (20px / 2) * (-1));
```

so i want output to be (10 + 10) * (-1) = -20

how to write this?

Comment: the one you write is correct, what's the problem?

Comment: I'm recaiving wront output, but maybe this is problem with something else

Comment: the calc function is correct but the value is not because the width can't be negative , maybe the wrong output is because the value from the calc function is being ignored !!

Comment: I wonder why this question has been downvoted

Answer (score 0):

it's almost correct. just that width can not be minus. you need to do something like :

```
width: calc(100% - 10px * 2);
```